# What is $\mu_5$ in string theory?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, notation, duality

I have come across the quantity $\mu_5$ in string theory quite a lot but I have not found it explicitly defined anywhere.

The bosonic worldvolume action reads [1]

\begin{equation}
S = \frac{\mu_5}{g_s} \int d^6x [-detG_{1} \cdot detG_2]^{\frac{1}{2}} + \mu_5 \int B_6.
\end{equation}

a) What are the units of $\mu_5$?
b) what exactly is it?

[1] J. Polchinski and M. Strassler, “The String Dual of a Confining Four-Dimensional
Gauge Theory,” [hep-th/0003136].

Comment: $\mu_p$ is the RR charge: see [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9910053).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mu_p$ in general is the electric Ramond-Ramond charge associated to a p-brane that is coupled electrically to a (p+1)-form gauge field $C_{p+1}$. You can think of it roughly as a generalisation of electric charge to p-dimensional objects. Via Gauss' law, it is given by
$$
\mu_p=\int_{\mathbb S^{D-p-2}}\star\ \mathrm dC_{p+1}
$$

where the integral denotes the flux over a sphere enclosing the p-brane and $D$ is the number of dimensions of the theory. In the context of string theory, $\mu_p$ is dimensionless, and I also note that D-brane charges in type II string theory are famously classified by [K-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-theory).